# broadcast receiver issue need help?

Tags: android, broadcast

I created a broadcast receiver. After that in onReceive, I received an information and called a method in the class.

my question is when I call that method I want to call only once but why it calls more than one time?

Are there any way we can determine that onReceive receive only one ???

**EDIT**

my method that I call in onReceiver is update map location in class extend MapActivity

I also register my broadcast service in manisfest.xml

**I want to add comment to the answer but i can't i don't know why**

how can we determine to our broadcast receiver to receiver only one??
thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate about for which broadcast receiver you are using ?

Comment: actually it is a manual create broadcast so no specific one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can maintain a `bool` variable and when you get call first time in the method, make this `bool` `true` and next time before calling the method you can put check there using this `bool` variable.

If you are not registering your receiver in the manifest file then you can use this bool value before registering the receiver.